# Vue3 typescript luxon type error in vue files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron, vite, luxon

I have a Vue3 + Vite + Electon project.

I wanted to use Luxon package to replace the outdated moment package.

`npm install --save luxon`

and in normal ts files I can use it as normal

when importing in any vue component

`import { DateTime } from 'luxon';`

It throws this error:

> "Could not find a declaration file for module 'luxon'. 'path-to-module/luxon.js' implicitly has an 'any' type".

I also tried to install

`npm i --save-dev @types/luxon`

This doesn't solve my problem.
Any suggestion?

Marcel

Comment: Have you tried restarting your typescript service or IDE?  You might need to do this to get the newly installed types recognized.

Comment: Yes, but that helped I got an vscode error of volar ts and reinstalled it and now it is working! Thx a lot